# Using the gem paper_trail for tracking the latest news-activity on my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using the gem `paper_trail` for keeping track of versions. I wonder, is there any way to create some kind of activity news out of the models it's been included into? For example, I've added it into the models Commentary, User and Article. I want to be to get a list of the latest changes of these models and create something like news of activities:

- user A has created a new Category
- user B has edited an Article
- admin had added a new Article
- etc

Is it possible? And how? Seems like yes, but how exactly? Note that, I don't want to retrieve that kind of information from all the models I've included the gem into, but only from the ones I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want it by the user, you should integrate https://github.com/ankit1910/paper_trail-globalid to link the whodunnit part.

```
PaperTrail::Version.where_object(attr1: val1, attr2: val2)
```

> NOTE:  `paper_trail` gem is for auditing.
>   Do not forget to check your `indexes` on your database since relational databases slow as your no. of indexes increase.

Based on my experience with `[spree][1]` framework and a similar gem, `versions` table was the largest we had and it grew quiet fast. You may face similar challenges in maintaining this table and adding indexes may cause it to slow down.

My suggestion would be to use a Redis like store to maintain a list of 10 or so recent updates per user which the user may be notified of instead of querying MySQL (essentially caching)

Comment: can I use the gem paper_trail only? and how.

Comment: you need to use the other methods exposed. there is a whodunnit column. you can use that to do it. see the README of paper_trail gem to understand the API it exposes.

Comment: I don't understand what you said. **can I use the gem paper_trail only?**

Comment: Yes. Since its writing all your data, it will have the capability to read as well.